# Error in producer and consumer code of generating data in Spark + Kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to stream data from a CSV file via Kafka in Pyspark. The code for my producer is:

```
KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "songTopic"
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS = 'localhost:9092'

kafka_producer_obj = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS,api_version=(0,10,1),
    value_serializer=lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))

filepath = "tracks.csv"
songs_df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

for message in song_list:

        print("Message Type: ", type(message))
        print("Message: ", message)
        kafka_producer_obj.send(KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS, message)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The code for my consumer is:

```
kafka_topic_name = "songTopic"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092'

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Reccomendation System") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# Construct a streaming DataFrame
songs_df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .load()
```

I first run the producer code and then the consumer code and the errors I get for them are respectively as follows:
[Producer code]

```
KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.
```

[Consumer code]

```
AnalysisException: 'Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;'
```

Some other information is that I am running this through 2 Jupyter notebooks and have only installed `pyspark` and `kafka-python`. I am not really sure what to do hereand how to resolve these errors.

Comment: 1) where is Kafka running? Is it actually running? 2) please limit your posts to single errors; focus on making the producer code work. Spark doesn't come with Kafka packages and you should search the error to find the solution `Failed to find data source: kafka`

Comment: hi, did you solve this problem? I encounter this type of problem too